# Android RxJava2 Retrofit and ViewPager

Tags: android, retrofit

I'm using RxJava2 and Retrofit with ViewPager and I faced this error
**io.reactivex.exceptions.OnErrorNotImplementedException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $**

My code below 
Pojo class

```
public class Photo {
    private String name;
    private String imageUrl;

    public Photo() {
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getImageUrl() {
        return imageUrl;
    }

    public void setImageUrl(String imageUrl) {
        this.imageUrl = imageUrl;
    }
}
```

**interfaces**

```
public interface inNetworkManager {
Observable<Photo[]> loadPhotos();
```

}

```
public interface inServices {
    @GET("heroes.php")
    Observable<Photo[]> loadPhotos();
}
```

**NetworkManager class**

public class NetworkManager implements inNetworkManager {
    private inServices services;

```
public NetworkManager() {
    initData();
}

private void initData() {
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .build();
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(CommonsKt.getBASE_URL())
            .client(client)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
            .build();
    services = retrofit.create(inServices.class);
}

@Override
public Observable<Photo[]> loadPhotos() {
    return services.loadPhotos()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());

}
```

}
**Adapter**

public class QuetoPhotoPageAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

```
private ArrayList<Photo> list;
private LayoutInflater inflater;
private Context context;
private AppCompatImageView imQueto;

public QuetoPhotoPageAdapter(ArrayList arrayList, Context context) {
    this.list = arrayList;
    this.context = context;
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return list.size();
}

public void addPhotos(Photo[] photos) {
    list.clear();
    notifyDataSetChanged();
    Collections.addAll(list, photos);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@NonNull
@Override
public Object instantiateItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, int position) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_view, container, false);
    imQueto = view.findViewById(R.id.imQuote);
    Picasso.get()
            .load(String.valueOf(list.get(position)))
            .into(imQueto);

    container.addView(view, 0);
    return view;
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(@NonNull View view, @NonNull Object object) {
    return view.equals(object);
}
```

}

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity {
private ArrayList<Photo> list;
private QuetoPhotoPageAdapter adapter;


@Override

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    addNet();
    init();
}
/*new Consumer<Photo[]>() {
                @Override
                public void accept(Photo[] photos) throws Exception {
                    adapter.addPhotos(photos);
                }
            }*/

private void addNet() {
    inNetworkManager manger = ((App) getApplication()).getManager();
    Disposable d = manger.loadPhotos()
            .subscribe(photos -> adapter.addPhotos(photos));
    addDispose(d);

}
 private void init() {
        adapter = new QuetoPhotoPageAdapter(list, MainActivity.this);
    }
```

Comment: You get Object from your server, not array

Comment: What shoul I do?

Comment: You should change `@GET("heroes.php") Observable<Photo[]> loadPhotos();` to `@GET("heroes.php") Observable<Photo> loadPhoto();`

Comment: Also it would be better you show only your pojo, interface and JSON so i can clear my answear

Comment: I have just answered it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51264832/1177865). Possible duplicate question of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51264832/1177865).

Answer (score 1):

This error occurs mostly when there is mismatch in the Pojo which is a object but your JSON format is of array. First create a pojo while will give list of photo

```
package com.example;

import java.util.List;
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Example {

@SerializedName("heroes")
@Expose
private List<Hero> heroes = null;

public List<Hero> getHeroes() {
return heroes;
}

public void setHeroes(List<Hero> heroes) {
this.heroes = heroes;
}

}
```

After this

```
package com.example;

import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Hero {

@SerializedName("name")
@Expose
private String name;
@SerializedName("imageurl")
@Expose
private String imageurl;

public String getName() {
return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
this.name = name;
}

public String getImageurl() {
return imageurl;
}

public void setImageurl(String imageurl) {
this.imageurl = imageurl;
}

}
And 


  public interface inServices {
    @GET("heroes.php")
    Observable<Example> loadHeroes();
}
```

Comment: `{"heroes":[{"name":"Spiderman","imageurl":"https:\/\/simplifiedcoding.net\/demos\/view-flipper\/images\/spiderman.jpg"},{"name":"Iron Man","imageurl":"https:\/\/simplifiedcoding.net\/demos\/view-flipper\/images\/ironman.jpg"},{"name":"Thor","imageurl":"https:\/\/simplifiedcoding.net\/demos\/view-flipper\/images\/thor.jpg"},{"name":"Wolverine","imageurl":"https:\/\/simplifiedcoding.net\/demos\/view-flipper\/images\/wolverine.jpeg"}]}`

Comment: check every field which is case sensitive i.e. you have written imageUrl which should be imageurl.
or you can use
 @SerializedName("imageurl")
  private String imageUrl;

Comment: if it worked correct the answer any error feel to ask again?

Answer (score 0):

You shoud chande your Pojo due to your JSON

```
public class Hero {
   @SerializedName("name")
   @Expose
   private String name;
   @SerializedName("imageurl")
   @Expose
   private String imageurl;
}

public class HeroResponse {
   @SerializedName("heroes")
   @Expose
   private ArrayList<Hero> heroes = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

So your interfcae will look like this

```
public interface inServices {
    @GET("heroes.php")
    Observable<HeroResponse> loadHeroes();
}
```