# Error on retrieving JSON field in Retrofit 2.0

Tags: android, gson, retrofit2

I have a problem.
I'm using `Retrofit 2.0` to make calls to my api from my Android app. All works fine, but when I'm receive a empty field I get this error:

> Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 8599 path
>   $.meta.pagination.links

The problem is with links field, that sometimes is not empty

```
"links": {
    "next": "http://www.example.com,
 }
```

But when it's empty the error appears.
My questions, How can i handle when the links field is empty?

This is my whole response:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
        .....
        }
    ],      
    "meta": {
        "pagination": {
            "total": 50,
            "count": 50,
            "per_page": 60,
            "current_page": 1,
            "total_pages": 1,
            "links": []
        }
    }
}
```

And this my POJO class:

```
public class ListResponse<O> {

@SerializedName("data")
private List<O> lista;
@SerializedName("meta")
private Meta meta;

public List<O> getLista() {
    return lista;
}
public String getNext() { return meta.getPagination().getLinks().getNext(); }
public int getTotal() { return meta.getPagination().getTotal(); }

public class Meta {

    @SerializedName("pagination")
    Pagination pagination;

    public Pagination getPagination(){  return pagination; }

    public class Pagination{

        @SerializedName("total")
        int total;
        @SerializedName("count")
        int count;
        @SerializedName("per_page")
        int per_page;
        @SerializedName("current_page")
        int current_page;
        @SerializedName("total_pages")
        int total_pages;
        @SerializedName("links")
        Links links;

        public int getTotal() {
            return total;
        }

        public Links getLinks() {
            return links;
        }

        public class Links {
            @SerializedName("next")
            String next;

            public String getNext() {
                return next;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: paste your pojo class

Comment: change `Links links` to `List<Links> links`

Comment: I'll try this. Thanks!

Comment: try `custom deserialisation using gson-converter`, check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/46320656/8009433

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest [JsonDeserializer](https://static.javadoc.io/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.6.2/com/google/gson/JsonDeserializer.html). Some sample usage could be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31562157/gson-how-to-deserialize-array-or-empty-string) & [here](http://adavis.info/2014/10/android-custom-gson-deserialization-w.html).

Comment: Ok, I'll take a look.Thanks @hjchin

Comment: Perfect finding. But keep in mind that link only answers are not accepted as per community standards. So better would be to add some code here.

Comment: I'll take note on this. thanks.

Comment: Yes!! It's works @hjchin!!. And so sorry for my poor finding @PankajKumar :(